# Moving character to beginning of set list python

Tags: python, shift

Comparing files and listing them in order. If there is a '>', how can I move it to the beginning of the output file after using the code below to compare them. currently > is added to all lines

```
S = set()
for name in ['some_file_2.txt', 'some_file_3.txt']:
    with open(name, 'r') as f:
        S.update(f.read().split('\n'))

with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as f, open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        fo.write('|'.join(sorted(line.strip().split('|'), key=lambda x: x not in S))+'\n')
```

input files

file1 entries

```
>winter|mountain|snow
winter weather
>skate|slide
winter activities
>ice|water|freeze|melt
winter temperatures
```

file2 entries

```
water
juice
mountain
```

file3 entries

```
sea
ocean
slide
climb
```

Want output to look like this

```
>mountain|winter|snow
winter weather
>slide|skate
winter activities
>water|ice|freeze|melt
winter temperatures
```

How to modify or update the above script so that `>` is at the beginning/stays at the beginning of set and does not shift when they are sorted?

Comment: What does the input look like?  Is the `>` always at the start of the line?  If so, just remove it before you do the split, and put it back after you do the join.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `>` before splitting, then add it back when writing.

```
with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as f, open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            line = line.strip()[1:]
            fo.write('>' + '|'.join(sorted(line.split('|'), key=lambda x: x not in S))+'\n')
        else:
            fo.write(line)
```

Comment: I've updated to set a variable depending on whether the line begins with `>`